# Issue with Camera in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have `Activity` which contains `ViewPager` which implements `FragmentPagerAdapter` with 3 fragments and I have implemented Camera in one of the fragments using `SurfaceView`. So when users swipes to the left from my home fragment he is able to use Camera (like in WhatsApp). The issue is when starting app (where I get some data across internet and put into listview) or sometimes swipping to the left or right Camera appears in main or home fragment for a second or less and then disappers and home fragment is presented at it should be.

Here is the problem when downloading data, camera occupies home fragment until 
 data is loaded. And for now that is for a second or less:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsEUy.jpg

And this is how home fragment actually looks after downloading data:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUv3V.png

> I tried with adding background color to my home Fragment container xml
>   but that didn't work.

I followed this example to implement camer in fragment:
https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide/blob/master/camera/src/main/java/com/ultimate/camera/fragments/NativeCameraFragment.java

Can someone help or give some suggestions what's happening and what to do? Thanks

Comment: A code snippet would be more helpful.

Comment: Can u explain more about this .. i am not getting your point.what you wants.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added 2 images and description.

Comment: The Camera fragment is on the left, so it is the first, isn't it? When initialization is slow, the second ('home') fragment is not added to the pager. You should create all fragments first, and fill them with data (and camera preview) later.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks for suggestion. I tried that but that didn't work either as it happens also when I swipe from camera fragment back to the home fragment. Camera preview occupy home fragment for a sec and then dissaperas.

Comment: I found solution which works in my case. I posted as na answer if someone in future stuck in same problem. Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which fits my needs. So here it is if someone in future stuck with same issue. Somehow the problem was when I add my `CamerPreview` to `View` in my case that was `FrameLayout` and that was in `OnCreateView` of `CameraFragment`. Even if I try to start camera preview when `CameraFragment` is visible to user and stop preview when it's not visible that didn't help I was always getting flash over home fragment by Camera preview when swipping to the left or right.

So I create new Fragment which is like placeholder and I added it to `FragmentPagerAdapter` and then there was an option to create my `CameraFragment` using `FragmentTransaction` when my placeholder fragment is visible to user (that works too) but I used `ViewPager` detecting when user starts swipping to the left then `FragmentTransaction` begins to replace my placeholder fragment with actuall `CameraFragment`.

Transaction isn't quite somooth like for example in WhatsApp **(If someone knows how they done that and wants to share, that would be great)** but it's working without issues and no flashing over home fragment.

Of course if someone have and idea how to improve solution or some another better solution feel free to share it.

Comment: And if you use the deprecated Camera API, make sure you open the camera in a separate Handler thread (so that Camera.open() and callbacks do not cause congestion on the UI thread).

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks I found your explanation how to open Camera using `HandlerThread` vote up for that. And now it's more smoothly even I think `FragmentTransaction` glitches UI little.

Comment: Actually, WhatsApp is cheating on the camera fragment. When you swap left/right, the preview is not moving; it is only revealed more or less. This suggests (I didn't try to reverse engineer their layout, though it is possible) that they have the preview surface always ready under the other layers, and only have to deal with turning camera on or off in time. I believe this is a more robust approach than putting the preview surface in a fragment inside a ViewPager. Some devices may not be happy with camera preview surface being partially out of the actual screen.

Comment: That's interesting. I noticed that camera is not turnd on immediately when you swap left sometimes it waits probably checking is camera available and then turn on even layout is presented in some gray screen. But what do you think how they made swipe left to the camera without using `ViewPager` and fragment?

Comment: They probably use ViewPager, they could simply have a transparent fragment 'on the left' and camera view under the view pager.